# Back in Javascript after refresh

Tags: javascript

I know that    `history.go(-1)` and `history.back()` do this, but if I reload the page before running it, it doesn't go anywhere. How do I make it go to the *actual* previous page?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it should still work. Do you see the previous pages if you press and hold on the Back button?

Comment: yeah... it's really weird. Also if I use the back button, it goes back to the previous page.

Comment: works for me in Safari 11. What browser are you using?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many times you refresh the page as long as you stay in the same window (or, in our days, the same tab). This mechanic works is all browsers identically, and there should not be a case when it doesn't. The question therefore lacks important information.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 62 on Mac